# doubts on getting value of any word from editText

Tags: android

I have already Entered some text in my `editText`. I want to get the value of any word selected form the text to any variable.I already tried `textvaluechanged()` and `textwatcher()` but it seems i dint understand the concept ...

Comment: I think you want to use the split function to get your string separated by spaces into an array of strings. Just remove the punctuation chars and other garbage, then you're ready to split.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and point out what you think might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content of android's edittext by calling
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29)

Like this:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.{replace for ID of EDITTEXT});    
String inputString = edit.getText().toString();
```